# Periodic network latency peaks on mobile devices

Tags: networking, mobile, real-time

I was receiving UDP data packets in real-time around every 200ms from the server, and from time to time I got packets in the delay of even a couple of seconds.

I have put my UDP pings (from client-side) to 200ms and it made my network a lot more responsive, but that is all learned from experimenting.
I don't have a solid knowledge of why this worked.

I would like to understand how power conservation algorithms work on mobile devices because I think that is why this happened.

After some investigation the best thing I have found so far is
http://www.crittercism.com/2014/03/200ms-the-magical-number-for-faster-response-times/

But it has not so many details on the topic nor any reference to further read.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: @iheanyi suggest category please

Comment: I'm not sure how this could categorically be written off as "not a programming question" as written.  If there's not enough information given regarding the application in question, and that information would be helpful in answering your question, that is different from _off-topic_.  Oddly, the info for the _networking_ tag suggests that the tag itself is _off-topic_: 'For most programming questions use [network-programming] tag. Non-programming networking questions are off topic...'.  So, assuming your question is related to a programming issue, maybe it should be tagged _network-programming_.

Comment: Are you over a cell network or wifi? If you are on wifi are the devices and server local?

Comment: This sounds more like a server/sender and/or client/reciever issue rather than a network issue.  What is the network?  Given that UDP is best effort, it is unlikely such huge (10x) delays are from the net.  Are pkts lost?  Include screen captures and a diagram.  What changed?  Has this ever, never, or sometimes worked before?  What "Server"? Etc. Etc. Etc.

Comment: delays or drops?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably two ways to look at this question:

**Why is '200ms' so special**

Users can tell when something takes longer than about 200ms - 300ms. This might include not just the transmission time, but also the time spent by the mobile device to use that data. Practically speaking, this is an important balancing point. Assuming new data is continuously available and that the network *could* send an update at any time, it might be a waste of resources to be any faster than about 200ms.

https://medium.com/appdiff/magic-numbers-for-app-performance-45c7e3bc9e46

**Why does adjusting ping frequency seem to have an effect**

Many energy conservation algorithms do two things:

- Send/request updates only when necessary, *but...*
- Periodically let the network know you're still around

This defines another balance point, since seconds may pass between 'necessary' updates, and the network might check that you're still there before that point. By adjusting the ping, you might be indicating that "I'm still here, and want updates!" every 200ms.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm

This might not explain the effect you're seeing, but these would be some factors to consider.

Comment: Nagle is used by TCP/telnet, not UDP.  You pt about 200ms in human time is good.